# compare 2 JSON objects having nested fields in Java

Tags: java, json

I have 2 JSON objects
First

```
    {
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "address",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "NONE"
    },
    {
      "name": "age",
      "type": "int",
      "default": "NONE"
    }
  ]
}
```

and second JSON

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "age",
      "type": "int",
      "default": "NONE"
    },
    {
      "name": "address",
      "type": "string",
      "default": "NONE"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note that

1. fields object may not be always named "name","type" and "default"
2. the field values may not be always primitives. For example an
   address which is of type "ArrayList".

How do I compare the JSON objects in such cases since these are equivalent JSON objects except for field value ordering. I am using Java 11 for my work. I tried using a custom Field class and map individual fields element to the class and then sort it but then the solution is not generic.

Following is one solution I am trying

```
public class JsonComparator {
    public static boolean compareJson(String json1, String json2) {
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(json1);
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject(json2);

        JSONArray fields1 = obj1.getJSONArray("fields");
        JSONArray fields2 = obj2.getJSONArray("fields");
    
        fields1 = sortJsonArray(fields1);
        fields2 = sortJsonArray(fields2);

        for (int i = 0; i < fields1.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject field1 = fields1.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject field2 = fields2.getJSONObject(i);

            for (String key : field1.keySet()) {
                if (!field1.get(key).equals(field2.get(key))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static JSONArray sortJsonArray(JSONArray array) {
        ArrayList<JSONObject> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            sortedList.add(array.getJSONObject(i));
        }
        sortedList.sort(new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(JSONObject o1, JSONObject o2) {
                return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
            }
        });
        return new JSONArray(sortedList);
    }
}
```

but need to analyze the JSON objects since all the JSON object need not contain the field "fields" and one JSON can be superset of other so trying to see if a better library available to give a solution.

Comment: I'd start by taking those two json's and parsing them INTO objects. Show us some code and I'll be able to give you more help.

Comment: sample code is provided. Also I am surprised , why negative marking on the question?

Answer (score 0):

You could try JSONCompare from JSONAssert library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

with compareMode as STRICT,LENIENT,IGNORE_ORDER etc.

```
 public static boolean isTwoJsonEquals(JSONObject firstObj,JSONObject secondObj, JSONCompareMode compareMode){
    try {
      JSONCompareResult result = JSONCompare.compareJSON(firstObj, secondObj, compareMode);

      return result.passed();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try library *Josson & Jossons*. It has JSON join, set and compare operation.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Jossons jossons = new Jossons();
jossons.putDataset("json1", Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"fields\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"name\": \"address\"," +
    "      \"type\": \"string\"," +
    "      \"default\": \"NONE\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "      \"name\": \"age\"," +
    "      \"type\": \"int\"," +
    "      \"default\": \"NONE\"" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]" +
    "}"));
jossons.putDataset("json2", Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"fields\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"name\": \"age\"," +
    "      \"type\": \"int\"," +
    "      \"default\": \"NONE\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "      \"name\": \"gender\"," +
    "      \"type\": \"string\"," +
    "      \"default\": \"NONE\"" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]" +
    "}"));
```

**Subtract right from left**

```
JsonNode node = jossons.evaluateQuery("json1->fields <-< json2->fields");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
// Output:
// [ {
//   "name" : "address",
//   "type" : "string",
//   "default" : "NONE"
// } ]
```

**Subtract left from right**

```
JsonNode node = jossons.evaluateQuery("json1->fields >-> json2->fields");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
// Output:
// [ {
//   "name" : "gender",
//   "type" : "string",
//   "default" : "NONE"
// } ]
```

**Symmetric difference**

```
JsonNode node = jossons.evaluateQuery("json1->fields <-> json2->fields");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
// Output:
// [ {
//   "name" : "address",
//   "type" : "string",
//   "default" : "NONE"
// }, {
//   "name" : "gender",
//   "type" : "string",
//   "default" : "NONE"
// } ]
```

**Equals**

```
JsonNode node = jossons.evaluateQuery("json1->fields <==> json2->fields");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
// Output:
// false
```

**Not equals**

```
JsonNode node = jossons.evaluateQuery("json1->fields <!=> json2->fields");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
// Output:
// true
```

Comment: I need the "Equals" result to be true. Have not tried this solution yet but looking at your answer, seems the equals will return false?

Comment: I've changed one of the "address" to "gender" to show the operations. You can change it back to test.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use JSONAssert for test and JSONCompare/ JSONCompareResult for logs.
It would look like this:

```java
public static void assertJSONEqual(String expected, String actual) throws IOException, JSONException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode expectedJsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(expected);
        JsonNode actualJsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(actual);
        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedJsonNode.toString(),actualJsonNode.toString(),true);
     
    }
```

or:

```java
 public static void assertJSONEqual(String expected, String actual) throws IOException, JSONException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode expectedJsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(expected);
        JsonNode actualJsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(actual);
        JSONCompareResult result = JSONCompare.compareJSON(expectedJsonNode.toString(),actualJsonNode.toString(), JSONCompareMode.STRICT);
        
        System.out.println(result);
       
    }
```

and needed imports:

```
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompare;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompareMode;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompareResult;
```